How to break an iteration and modify parent with child value in a nested list using java streams
I have this scenario:
public class A {
    private String aValue;
    private List<B> bList;
}

public class B {
    private List<C> cList;
}

public class C {
    private String cValue;
}

I want to update aValue with cValue when a given condition is met and then break all the iterations.
So far I've done this, but the search doesn't break when the first condition is met:
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();

aList.forEach(a -> {
    a.getBList.forEach(b -> {
        b.getCList.forEach(c -> {
            if(c.getCValue().equals("01")){
                a.setAValue(c.getCValue());
            }
        });
    });
});


Use loops instead. Streams are not the correct solution for everything and are not meant as a substitution for loops.

tbh, this tortuous operation to set a value based on another somewhere else is highly suggestive of a basic design problem

Like someone says in comments, streams might not be the best solution for this scenario, but if you still want use streams you may try adding flatMap to map all b streams to one and than you can use a filter
This version flattens the streams of B objects into one stream using flatMap, then applies a filter to find the first C object with the desired value. If found, it sets the corresponding A value.
aList.forEach(a -> 
    a.getBList().stream()
        .flatMap(b -> b.getCList().stream())
        .filter(c -> c.getCValue().equals("01"))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(c -> a.setAValue(c.getCValue()))
);


Warning in RED: You should never mutate your streams!   a.setAValue(c.getCValue() is a terrible idea.

@ZahidKhan a is not a Stream. It's a lambda parameter to the forEach function on a List.

@ZahidKhan if they removed or adding something from aList you would be right, but this is not the case.

@ZahidKhan it's not a good practice to update values in a stream (but this one is a property we not updating the elements references), but as far as I know it's a better option if we want to stick to streams.

@ZahidKhan forEach() and ifPresent() can only operate through side-effects by definition. As the operations used here are non-interfering, it is ok. Moreover the setValue() is called on items of the forEach(), so not even part of a stream pipeline.
